# Active Record embed Table.where('x').count inside of select statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm setting up an AR query that is basically meant to find an average of a few values that span three different tables.  I'm getting hung up on how to embed the result of a particular Count query inside of the Active Record select statement.

Just by itself, this query returns "3":
`Order.where(user_id: 319).count` => **3**

My question is, can I embed this into a select statement as a SQL alias similar to below:
`Table.xxxxxx.select("Order.where(user_id: 319).count AS count,user_id, SUM(quantity*current_price) AS revenue").xxxxx`

It seems to be throwing an error and generally not recognizing what I'm trying to do when I declare that first count alias.  Any ideas on the syntax?

Comment: You need to make an sql query with all your tables in it. I'd suggest you look it up a bit in terms of sql first. It's like trying to eat your spoon... You don't eat your spoon, you eat WITH your spoon...

Comment: @RubyRacer  I do have a SQL query with my tables in it, I just pasted the portion of my query that's throwing the error above.  Out of the context of my entire DB schema, the entire query would be really hard to understand what's going on which is why I just pasted in the problem section (isn't that the right SO protocol anyways?)

Comment: I'll have time in a couple of hours to supply an answer, if you still need one.

Comment: I'd love one @RubyRacer, any time you're able to put it together.  I'm wracking my brain over this one but it doesn't seem like it's getting much SO attention as of yet

Comment: Ok, here I am... Trying to figure out what the 3rd model is. I'd like to know what each table contains. I see that you have user_id from Order, Table is your main query table and the 3rd is what, User? Please, update your question to contain how the tables are connected to each other (in terms of id, for instance user_id in orders for table users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after examining a bit, I cleared my mind into the ActiveRecord `select()` syntax.

It's a method that can take a variable length of parameters. So, your failing :

```
Table.xxxxxx.select("Order.where(user_id: 319).count AS count,user_id, SUM(quantity*current_price) AS revenue").xxxxx
```

After replacing proper SQL for your misplaced ActiveRecord statement, should be more of like this [be careful, you can't use `as count` in most cases, count is reserved]:

```
Table.xxxxx.select("(SELECT count(id) from orders where user_id=319) as usercount", "user_id","SUM(quantity*current_price) AS revenue").xxxx
```

But I guess you should need more a per-user_id-table.

So, I'd skip Models and go to direct SQL, always being careful to avoid injections:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT COUNT(orders.id) as usercount, users.id from users, orders where users.id=orders.user_id group by users.id')
```

This is simplified of course, you can apply the rest of the data (which I currently do not know) accordingly. The above simplified, not full solution, could be written also as:

```
Order.joins(:user).select("count(orders.id) as usercount, users.id").group(:user_id)
```